# Verifying a combinatorics identity with rth derivative of this function

Tags: combinatorics, derivatives

Problem 14 of the chapter IV of the Feller's book "An introduction to probability" reads as follows:

> From the result of problem 12 conclude that
> $$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n \choose k}{(ns-ks)}_r = 0\qquad\qquad(1)$$
> if *r<n* and for *r=n*
>
> $$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n \choose k}{(ns-ks)}_n ={s^n}{n!}. \qquad\qquad(2)$$
>
> Verify this by evaluating the *r*th derivative, at x=0, of
> $$\frac{1}{{(1-x)}^{ns-r+1}}{[1-{(1-x)}^s]}^n\qquad\qquad(3)$$

The problem 12 that was mentioned in the problem description, is a particular version of coupon collector's problem:

> A pack of cards consisting of *s* identical series, each containing n cards numbered *1,2,...,n*. A random sample of $r≥n$ cards is drawn from the pack without replacement. Calculate the probability $u_r$ that each number is represented in the sample.

The answer to this latter problem is
$$u_r=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k{n \choose k}\frac{{(ns-ks)}_r}{(ns)_r}\qquad\qquad(4)  $$
which is not so hard to arrive at. Also with this answer we can show that (1) and (2) hold. But my problem is with the verification with the *r*th derivative of (3). With direct differentiation, I calculated the below as the *r*th derivative at x=0:

$$\sum_{k=0}^r {r \choose k}{\frac{(ns-k)!}{(ns-r)!}}\sum_{\sum_{}{i_j}=k}{(-1)}^{k+n}{k \choose {}i_1,i_2,...,i_n} [\prod_{j=1}^n \frac{s!}{({s-{i_j}})!}]A(I) \qquad\qquad(5) $$

where *A(I)* is a function of the n-tuple $I=(i_1,i_2,....,i_n)$ and is equal to zero if at least one of the elements of *I* is zero, otherwise *A(I)* is one (I used [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem))

Now it is easy to verify that (5) become $s^n{n!}$ if *r=n* and zero for *r<n*, but still I can't see how the cumbersome summation (5) can be simplified to be something as straightforward as (1). I expected to be able to *reproduce* the summation (1) by differentiating (3); so how one can arrive at (1) by (5) or by differentiating (3)?

Thank you all.